# Flat multiplying of Solr score

Tags: solr, lucene

Is it possible to do a custom multiplication of the Score returned by Solr? We have a factor in the range of 1.00-1.30 based on our own formula and I wish to just multiply the "final" Solr score with this - without having it normalized.

I've tried using various boosts in DisMax, but none of them produce the desired result, because 1) custom value is added (not multiplied) to the score and 2) they are normalized (queryNorm) before addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to do this. Using the Extended DisMax query parser, introduced in 3.1, it offers all the same features as the normal DisMax, but with a few useful enhancements.

The one I needed was the `boost` parameter. It acts the same way as the `bf` parameter from DisMax, but instead of adding a normalized value to the score, it multiplies the boost into the score (without any normalization).

For more info, see the Solr Wiki on [ExtendedDisMax](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax)